# Install Truecrypt on a MacBook for whole disk encryption of the Win7 partition in GPT mode?

Tags: windows-7, osx-lion, truecrypt, disk-encryption, filevault

I see a 2009 post at http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showpost.php?p=1590313&postcount=3 which ALMOST gets me there but requires MBR partitioning style. Anyway, I followed that and got:

1. Mac OS X Lion (10.7.2)
2. Windows 7 x64 Prof (whole-disk-encrypted, WDE, via Truecrypt)
3. MBR style disk partitioning (**<== issue!**)

However, I need to make this work as a GPT system because I need to turn on FileVault2 on Mac OS X and FileVault2 wants GPT, not MBR :(

When I directly tried turning TrueCrypt whole disk encryption, on my GPT system Truecrypt kept complaining that I didn't have 32Kb free space at the start to install the Truecrypt bootloader. Like the post above, I suspect TrueCrypt expects a 512byte MBR (sector 0) and then looks for 32KB blank space. However the GPT itself takes the first 34 sectors (17Kb), so Truecrypts logic fails.

Does anyone know how I can get 
Mac OS X Lion (FileVault2) and
Windows 7 x64 Prof (Truecrypt WDE)
working on a Mac?

Thanks

Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At face value this is a different question but the underlying issue of securing both windows and lion on a single machine are solved at

[How to encrypt ONLY a user's profile folder (e.g.: /User/sid) on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2?](https://superuser.com/questions/361513/how-to-encrypt-only-a-users-profile-folder-e-g-user-sid-on-mac-os-x-lion-1/379926#379926)

In short, run Windows 7 as a virtual machine inside lion, turn on filevault for lion.